# How to open a Browser popUp window from Actionscript ( Flash )?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, browser, popup

How to open a Browser popUp window from Actionscript ( Flash )? ( Any Code sample would be wary appreciated )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to call Javascript from Flash is with the `ExternalInterface` class.

Comment: you meant `ExternalInterface` :P

Comment: @jonathanasdf: Duh. My brain hurts. Thanks, and edited to reflect the brain cramp.

Answer (score 2):

From Adobe's [Create pop-up browser windows](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14192.html):

```
var jscommand:String = "window.open('http://www.adobe.com','win','height=200,width=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');";
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);");
navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

Running this will open the popup. This is for AS3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a JavaScript function from Flash to do this.